# How to find a String in a file in java and get String next to it?

Tags: java, file, file-handling

Suppose I have a file like this:

```text
Name: someone1 surname
Age: someNumber1
Height: whoCares1
Weight: someWeight1

Name: someone2
Age: someNumber2
Height: whoCares2
Weight: someWeight2

Name: someone3
Age: someNumber3
Height: whoCares3
Weight: someWeight3
```

And I want to get all the strings next to the "Name:" in an `ArrayList<String>`.

I only want to use `Scanner` class for this.

What I tried is getting the "Name:" part from the file using a code like this:

```java
while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            //read line by line
            String line = scanner.nextLine();

            //code to search for a word in the file which 
                if(line.indexOf("Name:")!=-1) {
                    // will search line by line for this word ignoring numbers in addition
                    // I find the word with this, what next?
                // I want to get word next to Name: and not only from one but from all the instances of the word Name:
                }
                else
                    System.out.println("does not");


        }
```

I want to get word next to "Name:" and not only from one but from all the instances of the word "Name:".

How can I do this?

**Edit:**

Also, how do I separate strings inside the file, for example if I want to store Name of first person in file as `someone1` in one ArrayList and `surname` in another ArrayList. How do I separate them, and get them to be stored in new ArrayLists.

Comment: Please don't change your question after others have already given answers.  This is especially true if your changes would invalidate those answers.

Comment: If your requirements have changed, then you should at least show us what the new data looks like.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I did not change the question, this is just an addition to what you've answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using `String#matches` to identify the lines of interest:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    if (line.matches("^Name:.*")) {
        names.add(line.replaceAll("^Name:\\s+", ""));
    }
}
```

The idea here is to grab all lines which start with `Name:`, and then remove the `Name:` prefix, leaving behind the content you want.

Explanation of regex used:

```
^      from start of string (line)
Name:  match text 'Name:'
\\s+   followed by any number of spaces (or other whitespace)
```

So by removing `^Name:\\s+`, we should be left with just the name information to the left of this.

**Edit:**

If, for example, your name content were actually a first and last name, then each line would look something like this:

```
Name: George Washington
```

In this case, if the format be fixed, we could try using `String#split` to isolate the first and last names:

```
String[] parts = line.split("\\s+");
String first = parts[1];
String last = parts[2];
// then store first and last in separate lists
```

What you would do exactly depends on your actual data.  There are many edge cases here.  Perhaps some lines only have a single name, or maybe some lines have a middle name, an initial, suffix, etc.  This is just to give you a general idea.

Comment: thank you for your answer, can you tell how does `names.add(line.split("\\s+")[1])` work to add the string next to "Names:" from the file?

Comment: @Manhar Reload the page, as I have changed my answer since then.

Comment: Yes, it works for the exact data you happen to show in the question, _but_ it would fail if names could have spaces in them.  The version above is safer to use, unless you are absolutely certain that no names would ever have whitespace.

Comment: That's cool to know, thank you. One last thing, can you tell how does "^" and "*" work, I know about "\\s+" in regex, but can you tell how does these strings add to the functionality of the code.

Comment: ^ means exactly from here  and .* anything after this is ok

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can you please answer the edit part of my question too? Thank you.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen shouldn't it be `first = parts[0]` and `last = parts[1]`?

Comment: No, because `parts[0]` should always be the `Name:` prefix on each matching line.  You want the second and third components.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Ah, got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a functional approach to extracting a list of names from a supplied file:

```
public List<String> getNames(File file) throws IOException {
    return Files.lines(file.toPath())
            .filter(str -> str.contains("Name: "))
            .map(str -> str.split("Name: ")[1])
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: While this may give a valid result, consider that OP said: _I only want to use Scanner class for this._